# How to setup static IP with wireless interface and netplan on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: server, 22.04, systemd, netplan

I am trying to setup a static ip for a ubuntu server 22.04 instance on a laptop. I though I am going to do that by modifying netplan configuration.

IP of router is 192.168.80.32
netplan config file is
00-installer-config

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.80.222/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.80.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "bssid":
          password: "pass"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.80.32
```

after generate and apply the ip does not change. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're running `networkd,` correct (`sudo service systemd-networkd status')? Had to check assumptions.

Comment: @richbl correct networkd. no networkmanager or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am sorry I think I found where the problem is. It should be written false instead of no in the lines where it asks about dhcp. I will consider this as **SOLVED**. Sorry if anyone has wasted their time.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.80.222/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.80.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "bssid":
          password: "pass"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.80.32
```

Comment: Glad that you resolved your issue. Please mark the question as solved so this question can be closed. Thanks

Comment: I can't at the moment. it shows "You can accept your own answer in 2 days".